Request.Browser.Browser is returning Chrome even when I am using Edge
I am using ASP.NET application.
In a ASP.NET Page, I am trying to determine the Browser's name from the Request object.
In the Page_Load event of ASP.NET Page, I am checking the Request.Browser.Browser property. This property's value is "Chrome" even when I am using Edge browser. How can I find out the correct value?

Well, Edge browser now uses and is based on the Chrome engine, so that's what it goiong to return. since Edge is now based on chrome, then what is returned is a "chrome" based browser. You really can't much determine anything more, and thus it now days recommended to write JavaScript code based on "features" as opposed to some particular browser. They all now should be HTML5 compliant browsers anyway, so it not going to matter much anymore.  But, yes, Edge now returns that it is a chrome based browser, and there is little more you can do but accept that it returns you using a chrome browser.
